# JSPM fails to load Angular2

Tags: angular, jspm

I followed this [cheat sheet](https://gist.github.com/robwormald/429e01c6d802767441ec) to make the Angular2 run using JSPM.

Everything seems to work except one thing, I get this message in browsers console:

```
http://myapp.loc/vendor/jspm_packages/npm/angular2@2.0.0-beta.17/angular2.js 404 (Not Found)
```

The URL is not correct and in the file system I see it should be like:

```
http://nettebase.loc/vendor/jspm_packages/npm/angular2@2.0.0-beta.17/bundles/angular2.js
```

Note the **bundles** part. When I include this manually it works but that is something I don't want to do.

What is wrong? I didn't specify that URL anywhere so I guess that JSPM manages that.

I am new to all this stuff so it is all magic to me, so I followed the tutorial and this is something I seem unable to crack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that those examples use old Angular2 version, in current version you should use imports like this:

```
import {
    Component
} from 'angular2/core';

import {
    bootstrap
} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
```

Instead of

```
import {
    Component,
    bootstrap
} from 'angular2/angular2';
```

That is prevalent in many examples.

Comment: I have an example with Angular2 and JSPM here: https://github.com/fintechneo/angular2-templates